# Shaken, not stirred

Tags: mouthfeel, equipment

When making coffee and espresso concoctions at home I usually prefer them shaken, not stirred. I find that it changes the mouth feel and adds a nice head to cold drinks and even some hot drinks.

Is this a common practice in the coffee world?

Would your average barista have a cocktail shaker as a part of his/her standard kit?

Comment: Interesting and surely a nice touch for cold drinks. It sounds hardly practical for hot drinks though, just because of temperature control. If someone has links to share, that'd be terrific.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not, although more possible for financial reasons.  Shaking a coffee drink would either require a more sturdily constructed disposable cup, which would cost more money and create even more waste or a reusable shaker which would require cleaning in between customers which would cost money and time making the drink.  Either method would also incur a significant risk of losing the prepared drink in its entirety, necessitating a restart.  For a business, it's much less risky to simply let you customers stir their drinks.